# Wordpress - get post offset/posts page offset in single post page (outside the loop)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I would like to know how I could get the offset of a custom post or its page, outside the get_posts loop.

I developed an external web application which connects to the wordpress blog with JSON API plugin, and show a given posts page using an AJAX request like :

```
?json=get_posts&orderby=date&order=desc&count=x&page=n
```

(This will return the nth page of x posts)

This works well, but now I would like to set a link on the wordpress blog "single post" page to this application, like "Show this post in app", with the current page offset as parameter. So I will be able to read this param in the app and get posts of the page containing the post, and highlight this post (sent as parameter).

If I can get the offset, I will be able to show the right page with a modulo operator :

> If offset = 22 and count = 10, show page 3 and highlight post n°2

```
page = Math.ceil(offset / count);
post_to_highlight_position = offset % count;
```

Do you know how I could do that? or if there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some researches I finally find a way to do that with a custom SQL query.
Here is how I achieved this :

First, I got the SQL query generated with WP_QUERY by adding this code :

```
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

//write the SQL query
echo $query->request;
```

I got something like :

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'work' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Which returns the complete list of posts, ordered by newest first. Then I added the `offset` by simply declaring an offset variable and increment it in every row, like that :

```
SET @offset=0;
SELECT wp_posts.ID, 
       @offset := @offset + 1 AS offset
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'work' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Last step, I filtered this list of ID + offset associations by post ID and add the custom rows (`page` and `position`) :

```
SET @offset=0;
SELECT ID, 
       offset - 1 AS offset, 
       CEIL(offset / 10) AS page,
       (offset - 1) % 10 AS position
FROM (SELECT wp_posts.ID, 
      @offset := @offset + 1 AS offset
      FROM wp_posts 
      WHERE 1=1 
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'work' 
      AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
      ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC) 
      AS OFFSETS
WHERE ID = 83
```

(where 83 is the searched post ID and 10 the number of posts per page)

I used `offset - 1 AS offset` to get offsets from 0, but you can just use `offset` to get offsets from 1.

So this will return the following tables :

id=83, posts per page = 10 :

```
ID | offset | page | position
83 |   16   |  2   |    6
```

> -> 6th position on page 2

id=10, posts per page = 5 :

```
ID | offset | page | position
10 |   33   |  7   |    3
```

> -> 3th position on page 7